# Compute sift descriptor for a given patch

Tags: image, dataset, matching, sift, vlfeat

I'm trying to compute sift descriptors for image patches present in the Winder-Brown [liberty dataset](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mbrown/patchdata/patchdata.html). These 64x64 patches seem to already have been rectified w.r.t affine transformation and rotation. I am using the vl sift library for computing the descriptors and the code I'm using (bypassing the feature detector) is

```
[~,D1match] = vl_sift(patch1,'Frames',[32.5;32.5;1;0]);
```

the problem is that I'm not sure this is working since matching results are very very bad. Any of you ever used this dataset and have some hints to correctly compute SIFT descriptors for these patches?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? or Did you figure out a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Using vl_feat's SIFT implementation, try to draw SIFT descriptor on the image path and visualize it: maybe you're using a too large scale factor, the descriptor gets evaluated outside the boindaries of the image and the matching will be very poor